# angular Reactive from dynamically adding the contact numbers

Tags: angularjs, typescript

```
    <form [formGroup]="from" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    
       <div fromArrayName="ContactNos">
    
          <div *ngFor="let contact of from.controls.ContactNo; index as i">
             <input [formControlName]="i" placeholder="Conatach number">
          </div>
       </div>
    </form>
    
    
    <button (click)="addContactNo()">Add New Contact</button>
    <button (click)="setPreset()">Add New Contact</button>




import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder,Validator, Validators,FormArray  } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers:[]
})
export class AppComponent {


  title='saho soft soln';
  signupForm : FormGroup;
  FirstName : string="";
  LastName : string="";
  Email : string="";
  Password : string="";

  constructor(private frombuilder : FormBuilder){
    this.signupForm=frombuilder.group({
      fname: ['', [Validators.required,Validators.maxLength(10),Validators.minLength(1)]],
      lname: ['',[Validators.required,Validators.maxLength(10)]],
      email: ['',[Validators.required,Validators.email]],
      userPassword : ['',Validators.required],
    });
  }
 
  from : any;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.from =  new FormArray([
      new FormControl('4654354'),
      new FormControl('42222'),
    ]);

    // console.log(this.from.get('ContactNos').value);
    // console.log(this.from.value);
  }


  addContactNo(){
    this.from.get('ContactNos').push(new FormControl());
  }


  setPreset(){
    this.from.get('ContactNos').patchValue(['12345','98765']);
  }
  
  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.from.get('ContactNos').push(new FormControl()));
    // console.log(this.from.value);
  }
}
```

1. in the above code I need to add contact number dynamically by clicking the button
2. on webpage load default  two number need to show
3. on a load of the webpage  only two buttons showing not input box
4. on add new contact number button need to be clicked
5. in the above code I need to add contact number dynamically by clicking the button

Answer (score 0):

There is not FormArray with this name `ContactNos` in your code. In `FormGroup` instance, there must be a FormArray. Hope The following code snippet will help you.
**form.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, FormArray  } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.scss']
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

  public form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private frombuilder: FormBuilder){ }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.frombuilder.group({
      ContactNos: new FormArray([new FormControl('4654354'), new FormControl('42222') ])
    });
    console.log(this.form.get('ContactNos').value);
  }

  /* Pushing New Contact to ContacNos Array */
  addContactNo(){
    (this.form.get('ContactNos') as FormArray).push(new FormControl());
  }

  /* Submitting Form */
  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.form.value);
  }

}
```

**form.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <ng-container formArrayName="ContactNos">
        <div *ngFor="let contact of form.get('ContactNos')['controls']; let i=index;"> 
            <input [formControlName]="i" placeholder="Enter contact number">
        </div>
    </ng-container>
 </form>
 
<button type="button" (click)="addContactNo()">Add New Contact</button>
<button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()">Submit Form</button>
```

Comment: not worked ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null

Comment: The above is a tested code. replace your code with this one and you will find it working.
As I said in my answer There is no`FormArray` with `ContactNos`. so whenever you want to push new `FormControl` in that array, it will throw this error.